# VS2015 Team Explorer showing solutions from node_modules

Tags: node.js, tfs, visual-studio-2015, npm, team-explorer

I just started using the npm package gulp-sass which relies on node-sass.

The node-sass package has a src folder, which includes a .sln file.

This .sln file shows up under my VS2015 Team Explorer Solutions heading. I really don't want that to happen.

Is there a way to exclude solutions placed under "node_modules" from being shown in the Team Explorer?

See attachment for documentation.[image]

Answer (score 0):

For TFVC, when you open the VS, then Visual Studio will **scan the local workspace for solution files.**

According to your screenshot, you are using GIT as your source control. This should be the same mechanism. VS will scan your local mapping repository. Unless you move the folders in your local repository, the solutions from node_modules will still shown in Team Explorer.

If you really can't stand this feature, you may have to create  a "dummy" repository for some folders including sln file on your machine and let Team Explorer scan that one every time you start up, instead.